# ElasticSearch: Pagination not working

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using below Elastic search using java client

```
SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch("titan")
.setTypes("vertex")
.setSearchType(SearchType.QUERY_AND_FETCH)
.setQuery(QueryBuilders.queryString("title:mytitle"))
.setFrom(start).setSize(1)
.execute()
.actionGet();
```

if `start` value is `0` it returns 3 result but if `start` value is `1` it returns 0 result.

I was expecting that if i pass 0 it will return first page , if 1 second page,2 third page ........ but its returning 3 result why?